# How to count words characters or sentence from uploaded file PDF, Doc, Xls, Csv, etc etc

Tags: java, php, zend-framework

How to count words from a uploaded file in PDF, Doc, Xls, Csv, etc etc. Either using PHP, Zend Framework or CLI based Java trigger ?

Comment: csv is easy. so you want tools to reverse-engineer pdf, doc, xls...?

Comment: Programmatically parsing PDF's is no small task. Your better off going with a 3rd party pdf reader and even those have issues when it comes to word ordering, but if you just need a word count they are pretty effective.  A PDF is laid out something like a collage.  There is no strict definition of a line.  What looks like a perfectly straight line to you, may be a huge mess geometrically speaking.

Comment: $wc filename.pdf or whatever gives this >  46   265 13025 file.odt

Comment: @pouncep, yes in linux i have this but which is wrong counter from terminal example: $ wc filename.pdf or filename.doc or filename.csv or filename.xls

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: 0.o which one is friendly for ZF and Java ? Is there no open source framework or libraries ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a third party app that does it http://www.globalrendering.com/download.html. You could create a simple wrapper for it.  As far as wc, its not accurate for those file types.  See http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=566407

Comment: Thanks, Oops, its a installation for windows platform. Nothing for CentOS or Fedora ?

Comment: Yes its true, wc is not accurate for other file formats. Seems very complicated part remaining out there under Linux platform for counting word etc, for a real time or interactive solution development.

Comment: Hm, well for the PDF part you could save as text and do a word count on a normal text file. There's a script http://blog.yeticode.co.uk/2009/03/get-pdf-word-count-in-linux/. Similarly for word, not sure how well it will work on excel.

Comment: I have 11 (words) it shows 10, is this how maximum guess we can reach  ?. ex: https://gist.github.com/759888

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should have a look at [tika](http://tika.apache.org/) 
which is written in Java, is free (Apache licensed) and can convert all formats you mentioned to text. After that, word count should be trivial.

You could also use linux command line utilities for converting to text, and write a simple wrapper around them.

(I cannot link to these for lack of reputation. Use your Google-fu.)

- pdf: pdftotext (part of xpdf). see also question #221359 on SuperUser.
- doc(x): abiword, catdoc, antiword, docxtotxt ... see also question 165978 on SuperUser.
- xls (and pretty much everything, but needs OpenOffice): [unoconv](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/)